# How do I use tabs with the Linux "Screen" program?

Tags: linux, tabs, gnu-screen

I'm using multiple screen windows and am wondering if it's possible to add a tabbed interface to it, with tab names and keyboard shortcuts for moving between the tabs.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add this to your *.screenrc* file:

```
caption always "%{= kw}%-w%{= BW}%n %t%{-}%+w %-= @%H - %LD %d %LM - %c"
```

After you restart your screen, there's a status bar below showing the current tab name, and as a bonus your current host name and time -- modify them away at will if you so wish.

To rename a tab, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> and give it a new name.

You can move between tabs (well, windows but think of them as tabs) with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>tabnumber</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> (go to next tab) / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> (go to previous tab).

Comment: I have something like this but use `hardstatus` instead of `caption`. The man page is vague about what the difference is. Anybody know?

Comment: @Doug: Hardstatus is usually for the messages thrown by screen for alerting you about different events. Caption is usually used if there are more than one window open. That's all I know -- both really seem to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I had `hardstatus alwayslastline` and a format string similar to your `caption` string so that it always shows interesting info. I've added `caption string` so that when I split the window, it's slightly different from what I show in the `hardstatus` line on the bottom.