# How to press Ctrl+a+A

Tags: gnu-screen

I was reading an answer about placing a tabs bar at the bottom of GNU Screen, and it said to press Ctrl+a+A. Clearly I cannot press A again while still pressing a, and why are the two capitalized differently?I have tried pressing Ctrl+A, Releasing, and than pressing A, which does nothing, and Pressing Ctrl+A, releasing A, and then Pressing it down again. Nothing of the sort works.
The answer is at: [How do I use tabs with the Linux "Screen" program?](https://superuser.com/questions/181100/how-do-i-use-tabs-with-the-linux-screen-program).

Comment: Can you post a link to that answer? maybe they ment CTRL-ALT-A?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/181100/how-do-i-use-tabs-with-the-linux-screen-program

Comment: looks like a failure in the documentation to properly inform the users on the proper keypresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

The answer you are referring to contains incorrectly formatted key bindings. To rename a window in GNU Screen press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, release both keys and then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. Conventional format to present this key binding is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/lkdb/screen.html) page you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to send commands to the outer screen, and then press a letter for specific keys.

So you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then release both, then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to send this <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: I [edited your answer](http://superuser.com/posts/755603/revisions) to add a hyperlink. I believe new users can add two per post, so just use `[text](http://url.com)` in the future to add a hyperlink to your question/answer.

Comment: @Chipperyman Thanks, I actually knew about doing this, but I was doing too many things at the same time and completely forgot. Thanks for adding though.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track... but be aware, that the command are *case-sensitive*.

So, to rename a GNU screen window do the following:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> together. Release them. Then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd> together. That makes a *capital* A.